# Media type unsupported error is showing while accessing HTTPS webservice using soap in IOS

Tags: ios, soap, https, using

**Code**:

```
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

 NSLog(@"returndata is %@",returnData);
```

**output**:

> <54686520 73657276 65722063 616e6e6f 74207365 72766963 65207468 65207265 71756573 74206265 63617573>

**Code**:

```
 NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnString is %@",returnString);
```

**output**:

> returnString is "The server cannot service the request because the
>   media type is unsupported".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolved this issue by binding HTTPS with HTTP. Now i can access the same webservice with SOAP.